# One to many relationships in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to figure out how to find a certain group of records using T-SQL and I'm having trouble figuring out how I would need to create the `WHERE` clause to do this.

I have a SQL 2008 R2 system that I'm working with, and in this database there are a couple of tables. One contains personnel records, and another contains addresses. The addresses relate to the personnel records by a foreign key relationship. So for example, to get a list of all personnel and all of their associated addresses (a single person could have multiple addresses) I could write something like this:

```
 SELECT id, name FROM personnel p
      INNER JOIN address a
      ON p.id = a.personnelid
```

However, each address has a column called `isprimary`, that is either 0 or 1. What I need to do is figure out how to find all personnel who do not have an associated address with `isprimary` set to 1. Or records that have no primary address.

Currently my thought is to build a temporary table with personnel who have addresses that aren't marked as primary. Then cycle through those and build a subset that have a primary address.

Then subtract the Personnel With Primary table from the results of Personnel With Non-Primary and I should have my list. However, I'm thinking that there has to be a more elegant way of doing this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this, it should get all Personnel rows with no matching primary address:

```
SELECT *
FROM Personnel p
WHERE NOT EXISTS
   (SELECT * FROM Address a WHERE a.personnelId = p.id AND a.isprimary = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, name FROM personnel p
INNER JOIN address a
ON p.id = a.personnelid
AND a.isprimary = 0
```

Comment: Don't think this will work, as `a.isprimary = 0` will also pick up addresses which have both `isprimary = 1 and isprimary = 0`

Answer (score 0):

This ends up beeing a [Left anti semi join](http://sqlity.net/en/1360/a-join-a-day-the-left-anti-semi-join/) pattern
and can be written like this:

```
SELECT id, name FROM personnel p
LEFT OUTER JOIN address a
    ON p.id = a.personnelid
    AND a.isprimary = 1
WHERE a.personnelId IS NULL
```

It can be interesting to test different ways because query plan are often not the same.